# Mysql : can't figure out what's wrong with this LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I would like to do a left join on the same table (licence) that only gives me licences that have no entry in the joined table. But I can't get any result :-(

Here is the query (quite simple actually) :

```
SELECT L1.licence_type, count(L1.id) as nb_licences FROM licence L1 
left JOIN licence L2 ON (L2.licence_number = L1.licence_number ) 
where L2.season = L1.season  and L2.league_id <> L1.league_id and L2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY L1.licence_type
```

The idea is to get only licences that has changed of league in the same year (I omitted the year's condition on purpose, to simplify the query).

Any idea would be apreciated.

As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/236345/alfabravo, here is my structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `licence` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `association_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `league_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `season` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_creation` datetime NOT NULL,
  `licence_number` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `licence_type` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_validation` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

As for licence_type (to aswer to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff), it's just a type like "competition", or "training", etc...

Comment: Please, include your tables definition and some example data. Hard to know what's wrong as this query MIGHT be right depending on what you want or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use left join  you should not use left joined  table's columns in where clause, in this way work as inner join, then add to condition the ON clause

```
SELECT L1.licence_type, count(L1.id) as nb_licences 
FROM licence L1 
left JOIN licence L2 ON (L2.licence_number = L1.licence_number ) 
    AND L2.season = L1.season  
    and L2.league_id <> L1.league_id and L2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY L1.licence_type
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation, this is working fine now :-)

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is to get only licenses that changed league in the same year

If you want licenses that changed league in a given year, I would think "group by":

```
select l.license_number, season
from license l
group by l.license_number, season
having min(league_id) <> max(league_id);
```

I am unclear on what `license_type` has to do with your question.